# Laravel 5.1 - compare Carbon dates

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-blade, php-carbon

Here I need to check does auction for article in my app is live so I write in Article model:

```
public function scopeCloseauction($query){
        $query->where(Carbon::parse('to')->subDays('auction_end'),'>',Carbon::now());
    }
```

and view I have:

```
@if ($article->Closeauction())
                            <td>
                           auction is live
                        </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                             auction is closed
                            </td>
                        @endif
```

but I have a problem becouse I got error:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I also try:
in model to add function:

```
public function isLive($to,$auction_end) {
    $first = Carbon::create($to).subDays($auction_end);
    $second = Carbon::now();
        return ($first->lte($second));
    }
```

and in view:

```
@if ($article->isLive($article->to,$article->auction_end))
                            <td>
                            live
                        </td>
                            @else
                            <td>
                                closed
                            </td>
                        @endif
```

but now give me this error:

> ErrorException in Carbon.php line 425: Unexpected data found.
>   Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Trailing data (View:
>   C:\wamp\www\project\resources\views\articles\index.blade.php)

Comment: I also try: public function scopeCloseauction($query){
        $query->where(('to').subDays('auction_end'),'>',Carbon::now());
    } but say: Call to undefined function App\subDays()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something add such function into your `Article` model:

```
public function isLive() 
{
    $first = Carbon::parse($this->to)->subDays($this->auction_end);
    $second = Carbon::now();
    return $first->lte($second);
}
```

and now in your view you can use:

```
@if ($article->isLive())
    <td>
      live
    </td>
    @else
    <td>
        closed
    </td>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here : `Carbon::parse('to')`. What do you want to do here ? the Carbon::parse method try to convert a string date into a Carbon date. [See the doc](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation). I dont think that Carbon can parse the string 'to'. If you want to check the diff between dates, [you should have a look](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) to the appropriated methods like `diffInDays`.